# How a particular Regex parses a content within nested html tags, Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, tags

I was doing a problem on regex java i.e

Read content between html tags, basically not just html tags but any valid starting and closing tags.

Suppose followings are sample input lines:

```
<h2>This is the content</h2>
<h1><h1>next content</h1></h1>
```

Output will be:

```
This is the content
next content
```

I found a regex solution which parses these input lines:
i.e

```
<(.+?)>([^<>]+)</(\\1)>
```

And following is the code which compiles regex and parses given input string

```
String[] input = {"<h2>This is the content</h2>","<h1><h1>next content</h1></h1>"};
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>([^<>]+)</(\\1)>");
  for(String line : input) {         
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
     while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(""+matcher.group(2));         
    }    
  }
```

Now I was able to understand how it parses the first input string,

```
<h1>This is the content</h1>
```

is parsed as

```
<(.+?)> --> <h1>, ([^<>]+) --> content within and </(\\1)> --> </h1>
```

But when it comes to parse nested tags, I could not make a concrete understanding on how it is being parsed:

```
 <h1><h1>next content</h1></h1>
```

I know that

```
<(.+?)> --> outer <h1> tag
```

but then `([^<>]+)` regex parses only `"next content" or entire inner "<h1>next content</h1>"` and which does the `</(\\1)>` regex matches first, whether inner `</h1>` or outer `</h1>` tag or how nested tags are being parsed.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: ...and this is why you **don't** parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). It is not possible to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: _"I know that `<(.+?)> --> outer <h1> tag`"_ That is either wrong or irrelevant, depending on how you look at it. You're _searching_ (`matcher.find()`) for a place where the regex matches, and the only place where it does is the _inner_ h1 tag. The outer h1 tag might as well not be there, or it might be any sort of garbage that isn't valid HTML, because it's completely ignored by your regex.

Comment: @Rawing and all of you, thanks for sharing information. I checked it by changing outer </h1> tag i.e making outer html tags as invalid and keeping inner html tags valid. It still worked fine, i.e outer tags were completly ignored and got "next content" as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because java.util.regex.Matcher#find looks for the next subsequence of the input, in case of

```
<h1><h1>next content</h1></h1>
```

it finds inner

```
<h1>next content</h1>
```

You can check this by calling 
                System.out.println(matcher.start(1));

Comment: Thanks for telling. I tried with matcher.start(1)... It gave 5 as index output. u were right...

Comment: @Rawing thanks for sharing info in useful comment above